# Extra Characters in email body

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

we have a problem with emails sent from CRM having extra characters added to the end, here is an example, this was sent from our system to a recipient in Germany - server locale is uk .  the body of the email was just 'This is just a test email.'

we are using dynamics crm 4.0 on rollup 21 for server, client and email router.  this particular email was sent using the web interface and email router.

does anyone have any idea where the extra text is coming from?

**UPDATE - we have tracked this back to an email footer being added by our sonicwall email appliance.  Will update again if we find out why it gets corrupted sometimes.**

Von: sender
Gesendet: Dienstag, 2. Oktober 2012 14:21
An: sender
Betreff: test 2 october CRM:0161013

This is just a test email.

Nw֝瞘銘r׶&jwk&WyҊȵ鹗ة׺˺ȇ溺׵繈馗畫zf)yص鎗{۾ر銙ٵǢǢ'«녫ױʱ陧ziǦڲ&+~z˦W몶iȺ{N鱩{z˶)+zˁ溘궗حvwzˮ)繋yʥNrj|뢛抷ܢzح˭罸xƑ란h.)箋tYG)xzޗj渚iԭ熪xj`ؐ+tڍ馚{ۍמi˚)׭Ӯפ+zqVtګ}۟

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't manage to find an really fix of find out why the Sonicwall was causing this, our exchange guy just moves the footer from there to the Excahnge server and it works fins now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is problem with mail server. I think you can add additional text on every outgoing email. Did you check configuration of mail server?